# play random video on each page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vuejs2

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.popup-youtube1, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
    disableOn: 700,
    type: 'iframe',
    mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
    removalDelay: 160,
    preloader: false,
    fixedContentPos: false
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
  <div class="thumb">
    <a class="popup-youtube1" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8E6xsac2MU">
      <img src="../.././images/kalchachani.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="hover-opaque">
      </div>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle text-center" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumb-caption text-center">
    <figcaption><a href="#">Anand Deshpande</a></figcaption>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
```

hello, I am using magnific popup JQuery plugin to play Youtube video in popup. here i had added single video link of youtube. when I click on the thumbnail it will play the video related to given URL.but, i want to play different video on each page refresh.

Comment: your snippet is not working

Comment: You need to get a list of youtube dump, then create function to randomly select them. You get the dump from Youtube API, do some more searching you will come across it.

Answer (score 1):

create an array and add video links to array then generate a random index to get video link from array

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <a class="vimeo-video-1" href="#">RANDOM VIMEO VIDEOS</a>
    <br>
    <a class="vimeo-video-2" href="#">RANDOM YOUTUBE VIDEOS</a>
</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var num = 3;

//VIMEO
vimeolink = new Array("212731897", "118901221", "211690338");
x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * num));
randomvimeolink = (vimeolink[x]);

//YOUTUBE
youtubelink = new Array("1F_bG-uJMns&start=90", "PjDw3azfZWI&t=31m08s", "PjDw3azfZWI#t=31m08s");
x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * num));
randomyoutubelink = (youtubelink[x]);


//VIMEO MAGNEFICE POPUP
$('.vimeo-video-1').magnificPopup({
    items: [{
        src: 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + randomvimeolink,
        type: 'iframe' // this overrides default type
    }],
    gallery: {
        enabled: false
    },
    type: 'image'
});


//YOUTUBE MAGNEFICE POPUP
$('.vimeo-video-2').magnificPopup({
    items: [{
        src: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + randomyoutubelink,
        type: 'iframe' // this overrides default type
    }],
    gallery: {
        enabled: false
    },
    type: 'image'
});
</script>
```